# JavaFX Video mp4 flv don't play outside IDE

Tags: video, javafx, mp4

I'm trying to play a video (mp4 or flv) in a MediaView in a JavaFX application. I had no problem doing so (using H.264-mp4) within the IDE (both Netbeans and Eclipse worked fine). But when running the actual runnable jar a codec/decoder(?) problem seems to occur:

Only when using Netbeans on Mac the following Warning is reported:

vtDecrompressopmDuctCreate signalled err=-8973 (err) (Could not select and open decoder instance) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia_frameworks/CoreMedia-1562.235/Sources/VideoToolBox/VTDecompressionSession.c line 1181

Then I converted the mp4 to flv files (which play flawlessly in a Flash video player). The flv files don't even play within the IDEs. 
Is there any way to convert the mp4 files to a fitting format or adding codecs to solve this problem?

Comment: I had the same problem playing mp4 outside the IDE the video is playing only once  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731022/javafx-mediaplayer-cyclecount-not-working

Comment: @GoXr3Plus it's crazy isn't it? I've found no way to circumvent that. I have converted my files to any kind of video format/audio format I could, none worked. Then I tried as an emergency solution to use a webview loading at the file hosted on youtube. Also that doesn't work outside the IDE. did you find another possibility?

Comment: Although it is playing one time the .mp4 and then stops.Do the following..Open the .mp4 with Firefox .If it plays it is ok .If not it will not play with JavaFX media player...